# Is there a way for an AJAX call to return both HTML content and callback functions?

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I need to update HTML div content and a JavaScript function to be called with specific parameters retrieved via AJAX after the AJAX request completes. Is this possible in one AJAX call?

Comment: yes it is...only if you try..where is the code sir?

Comment: You can do whatever you want in an ajax callback, just be more specific / show some code.

Comment: my experience is that you can simply provide document-ready-function inside the response and they will execute as soon as the dom is loaded into your current page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    callback();     //execute my callback function!!!
    }
  }
```

Your HTML will be inside the xmlhttp.responseText.

Comment: But what about specific parameters that go in that callback function that will be returned by the AJAX request?

Comment: i would suggest use jquery if you ajax regularly..it makes our job super easy and reduces the code length too..

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I will take your suggestion into serious consideration.

Comment: I ended up splitting up the returned AJAX request into JSON objects, one with HTML, others for parameters, so that I can update the DIV with the HTML, and call a function with the parameters in the section where callback() is

Answer (score 1):

jquery $.ajax supports callback after the request has been completed. 
Check the documentation -> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Without jQuery, if possible.

Comment: There is no mention of `jQuery` in the OP's question. We cannot assume they are using jQuery or have the ability to use jQuery.